# Sed keep matching past newlines

Tags: python, sed, jupyter, multiline

I'm trying to use sed to find and replace the multiline regex pattern of `eval_config: {.*}`.

I have a text file that contains something like this:

```
eval_config: {
  <variable number of lines and contents>
}
```

And I'd like to replace it with something like this:

```
eval_config: {
  <completely different variable number of lines and contents>
}
```

So how can I match and replace this? Using:

`sed -i 's/eval_config: {.*\+}/replacement_text/g' filename` seems to stop at newlines.

---

**Details:**

I'm using sed from a Jupyter notebook cell and constructing the new `eval_config` as a python multi-line string like this:

```
filename = 'file.txt'
new_eval_config_example = '''eval_config: {{
  metrics_set: {}
  use_moving_averages: false
  num_examples: {}
}}'''.format(metrics_set, val_count)

!sed -i '/eval_config: .*\+/{re.escape(new_eval_config_example)}/g' {filename}
```

**Updates**

- `<variable number of lines and contents>` won't contain a `}`
- it won't contain a nested `eval_config`
- terminating `}` will always be on its own line

Comment: You are intending to replace the innards or the whole thing?

Comment: Yeah or the entire thing, whichever is easier. I'm calling sed with jupyter notebook using `! sed ...` and the replacment text would actually be a multi-line python string. Added details to post.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Excluding jupyter issues, this seems to work: `sed ':again;$!N;$!b again; s/eval_config: {[^}]*}/\eval_config: {replacement text}/g'  testfile` Decided to just reorganize my workflow and use python's re module though with the `re.DOTALL` flag.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got around it!

Comment: Can `<variable number of lines and contents>` contain a `}`? Can it contain a nested `eval_config: {`? Is the terminating `}` always on a line on it's own? Those all make a big difference to a possible matching regexp so update your question to make that explicit.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the easiest way:

```
sed '/^eval_config: {/,/^}/c\
replacement\
more replacement' data.txt
```

Comment: What's it outputting? This selects `eval_config` range and changes it per replacement text.

Comment: I've never used the `c\` function in sed before. That's a nice solution!

Comment: It's returning `sed: can't read {filename}: No such file or directory`. Added more details to orig post to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu sed

```
r='replacement_text'
sed -E "/eval_config:\s*\{/ {N;s/\n[^\}]+/\n<$r>/}" filename
```